# container não respeita o min-height

Tags: css, html5, css3, div, layout-responsivo

Estou fazendo um programa apenas para treinar meus conhecimentos (nível iniciante) para mostrar na tela números impares, pares ou ambos conforme o numero informado no `input`, porém se o usuário escolher um número muito alto (a partir de *111* APENAS NA **OPÇÃO AMBOS**) o `.container` não acompanha o tamanho `height` do `.box` e `.result`. As outras opções funcionam

Porém, a partir do numero 193 tanto na opção numero par quanto impar o `.container` também não acompanha!
Não sei o que fiz errado, meu objetivo é apenas aumentar o `height` de todo o conteúdo (`.container`, `.box`, `.result`) conforme a sequencia numérica.

```js
submit.onclick = function() {
  result();
}


function result() {

  const informedNumber = document.querySelector('#informedNumber');
  const options = document.querySelector('#options');
  const printResult = document.querySelector('#printResult');
  //console.log(options.value);


  for (i = 0; i <= informedNumber.value; i++) {
    let number = i;


    if (number % 2 == 0 && (options.value == 'evenNumber' || options.value == 'bothNumber')) {
      //console.log( i + 'par');
      printResult.innerHTML = printResult.innerHTML + "<span class='even'>" + i + "</span>" + ' ';
    }

    if (number % 2 == 1 && (options.value == 'oddNumber' || options.value == 'bothNumber')) {
      //console.log( i + 'impar');
      printResult.innerHTML = printResult.innerHTML + "<span class='odd'>" + i + "</span>" + ' ';

    }

  }

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: auto;
  background: #bbdead;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  width: 350px;
  max-height: auto;
  background: #ccdead;
  border-radius: 50px 100px;
  border: 3px solid #eedead;
}

.content {
  padding: 15px;
}

.content h1 {
  margin: 25px 0 30px 95px;
  color: #1c8b21;
}

.content fieldset {
  color: #1c8b21;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 60px;
  border: none;
}

.content fieldset input,
select {
  margin: 10px 0 15px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-color: #1c8b21;
}

.result {
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #a4ab80;
  padding: 20px 35px 20px 35px;
  margin: 15px 0 0 50px;
}

.even {
  color: #f5e5b6;
}

.odd {
  color: #faca3a;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Treino</h1>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Escolha</legend>
          <input type="number" placeholder="Informe um número" id="informedNumber">
          <select id="options">
            <option>Opções</option>
            <option value="evenNumber">Números pares</option>
            <option value="oddNumber">Números impares</option>
            <option value="bothNumber">Ambos</option>
          </select>
          <input type="submit" value="enviar" id="submit">
        </fieldset>
        <div id="printResult" class="result"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Uma solução possível é inverter a regra de altura: o `height` do elemento `.container` ser `auto` e o `min-height` ser `100vh`.
(O `height` por padrão é `auto`, então não precisa ser declarado nesse caso)

Algo assim:

```
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh; 
  background: #bbdead;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```